# HLM vs. repeated measures ANOVA -- sphericity concerns?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, sphericity

All,

Say I have a 2 (between) x 4 (repeated measures) mixed factorial design. I was going to analyze it with ANOVA, but normality issues and sphericity concerns have made that not a good idea.

Are there any reasons why sphericity would PREVENT a valid HLM analysis? I was going to do a poisson model in lme4 (addresses the non-normality issue) ... but the sphericity is not an issue in a multilevel model, correct?

Comment: Can you provide more information on your problem? Also, you might consider adding the `mixed-models` tag to your question to get more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphericity shouldn't be a problem in mixed models, since they explicitly model the variance components separately. i.e. take a more comprehensive approach to calculating pooled variances which requires fewer assumptions but additional computational overhead.

More challenging in the mixed models context are the denominator degrees of freedom necessary for $F$ and $t$ tests. See for example the R FAQ ["lmer, p-values and all that"](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html).

Some mixed model packages even allow you to explicitly define the variance-covariance structure in your model.

Another useful search term for this question is "heteroscedasticity", which multilevel / hierarchical / mixed-effects models can handle when structured appropriately.